# Excel graph subclsification

Tags: excel, graph, excel-2010, excel-2013, columnsorting

I have this information from which I am generating a graph, but I would like to add a subclassification.

I currently have the table and graph as follows:
[image]
**I would like to know if there is any way to add a sub-classification so that 
something like this is left, taking the data from column A:**

[image]

Thanks for your support....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use "Pivot Table" & "Pivot Chart".

Go to "Insert" tab and click "Pivot Table". Select your data range and the position for your table. Arrange fields as appears on screenshot attached. After that, on the same "Insert" tab click "Pivot Chart" and configure it's style to match your requirements.

[image: Pivot table and Pivot chart]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without a pivot table. Remove the duplicates in column A, then edit the chart source, click the Edit button for the Horizontal Axis Labels and select A2:B7.

[image]

Or, if you want to use a pivot chart, then pull both **estado** and **nombre** into the row area of the pivot panel.

[image]